# FOSElasticaBundle / elasticsearch configuration for partial word matching

Tags: php, search, indexing, elasticsearch

I am very new in Search/Indexing and I am working on using Symfony's FosElasticaBundle to provide search functionalities to a web app. I've got it set up and running with no problem until I found that the default setting only allow full word search.

I then tried for a few hours to enable partial word matching without luck. I tried nGram and edgenGram etc. but I was really confused with all the concepts. I did try searching for tutorial on the concepts and configurations but not really getting the answers.

Here's my config:

```
fos_elastica:
  clients:
      default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
  serializer:
      callback_class: FOS\ElasticaBundle\Serializer\Callback
      serializer: serializer
  indexes:
      website:
          client: default
          finder: ~
          settings:
              index:
                  analysis:
                      analyzer:
                          index_analyzer:
                              tokenizer: "nGram"
                              filter:  ["lowercase", "snowball"]
                          search_analyzer:
                              tokenizer: "nGram"
                              filter:  ["lowercase", "snowball"]

                      filter:
                          snowball:
                              type: "snowball"
                              language: "English"
          types:
              client:

                  mappings:
                      BusinessName: { boost: 10 }
                      users:
                          type: "object"
                          properties:
                              firstName: { boost: 5 }
                              lastName: { boost: 5 }
                              email: { boost: 10 }
                  persistence:
                      driver: orm # orm, mongodb, propel are available
                      model: E1\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Client
                      listener:
                      provider: ~
                      finder: ~
```

The documentation isn't helpful. Can anyone give me some light on how to get partial word matching set and/or let me know where I can find tutorial on the concepts (tokenizer, filters, analyzer) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the default search: `$resultSet = $userType->search('bob');`, you will have a very limited set of the power of ElasticSearch.

Default code perform a `Query::create($query);`, which create a `QueryString` query.

[QueryString](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/query-string-query/) are great because you can write wildcard and it search on the **_all** field by default, so if you want **Po** to match documents containing **Pony**, you have to use `$userType->search('Po*');`.

No custom analyzer is needed here. The standard one already use spaces to separate words and lowercase everything.

About documentation and help, keep in mind that Elastica is a tool, the real search engine here is ElasticSearch, so the best advice I can give you is to write and prototype your queries in Json. You can use the Head plugin, or this [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense/doinijnbnggojdlcjifpdckfokbbfpbo).

Comment: But using ('Po*') will get all documents where 'Po' or 'po' no matter where there are placed - at start or at the middle or end. Is there any way to limit the search so only elements starting with 'po' is found?